# Macintosh- and Windows-compatible wired mouse with acceleration scrolling?

Tags: mac, windows, mouse, macos, multi-touch

I would like a mouse that is compatible with both Macintosh and Windows (although if I have to buy a different mouse for each platform, that's okay), and that you can scroll up and down with acceleration (as you can on a trackpad). I want to be in a file and be able to zip down to the bottom or zip up to the top with a fast flick of my fingers on the mouse surface, but to be able to go down and up slowly with a slower flick/drag of my fingers on the mouse surface (again, like you can on a trackpad).

I don't care much about other gestures.

Less important: I would prefer a wired mouse (connecting via USB a or USB c) since I don't mind the cord and don't want to deal with bluetooth connection or mouse charging issues.

I see that the Magic Mouse 2 can be made to work on Windows via some special drivers and custom settings, but I'm not so interested in that because I'd prefer not to mess with that, I prefer a wired mouse, and I'm hoping for something cheaper than $74.

I've searched a lot on Amazon but I've only found Win-specific gesture mice (like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072FG8LBV)). For Mac (aside from the MM2, [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NZ79XBY) is the closest I can find) And then some (like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GZJFGQS)) that claim compatibility with both (but often only show pictures for one platform) and look like they might let you scroll by dragging on the top of the mouse, but don't say so.

Comment: Why specifically '2-finger scroll'? A mouse with a wheel does one-finger scroll. On a trackpad it needs to be able to recognise 2-fingers as a separate action. A wheel doesn't need that distinction.

Comment: @Tetsujin, it's not so much about two fingers as it's about acceleration. With a trackpad I can flick up and down with two fingers quickly or slowly to control the speed the page scrolls. With a mouse wheel (as far as I know) you can only scroll a fixed amount per tick.

Comment: That's dependant entirely on the software controlling it. Personally I have different speed & acceleration values set per app - some I want fast & zippy with high accel, some i want slow & precise.

Comment: You have acceleration (slow and fast depending on how fast you flick) working with a mouse? Which mouse?

Comment: Any mouse. It's not the mouse that controls it, it's the software. Currently I have a Logitech Master MX2, which unfortunately I need to use Logitech's own software for. Prior to that I had a simpler mouse, though still an 8-button, which I ran using SteerMouse [or USB Overdrive is an alternative]. idk what Windows alternatives there are for that kind of precision control.

Comment: I think I didn't explain well enough. I'm not talking about the sensitivity of the mouse when you drag it on the table. I know I can set that with any mouse. I'm talking about the trackpad-style dragging or flicking of fingers on the surface of the mouse, as with a trackpad. I've added text to the OP to try to make it clear.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about - you can control wheel acceleration in just the same way as cursor acceleration. They're not tied, they can both be set per application, using the right software. A trackpad is not necessary for this functionality.

Comment: I suspect that a mouse with gestures like a trackpad for both Windows and Mac may be very rare, if it exists at all. Given that you want the functionality of a trackpad, is there any reason you've ruled out actually using a trackpad?

Comment: @Tetsujin, yes, I see now that mouse wheel acceleration is standard on Mac. On Windows unless you do something special you only get to choose the fixed number of lines (or pages) a wheel tick scrolls. I will try the mouse wheel on a Mac and see how it feels for me. (There appear to be programs that can improve the behavior on Mac, and make it happen on Windows.)

Comment: @benwiggy, yes, you would think I'd just need to get an external trackpad and it would do what I want. However, I have found over time that I'm just much more efficient and precise with a mouse than with a trackpad. So I really want a mouse, and I really want to be able to zip quickly (or slowly) up and down a file vertically. And I want it to be wired. And I want it to be cheap. And I want a pony.

Comment: But actually I realize I don't mind having a different mouse for each platform. So I could be good with this fancy Windows mouse: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B072FG8LBV. And a Magic Mouse 2 for Macintosh, or hopefully a lower-priced off-brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Logitech MX Master 3 has a unique scroll wheel that is on a flywheel.  So when it comes to large amount of scrolling it will spin freely. I spin it hard and it flies down the file.

Works on both mac and PC. Has a button on the bottom to switch between computers (connections).  It also has a feature (called "Flow") I don't use, which in theory would allow you to move the mouse cursor from one computer to another without changing which devices you're connected to, but I don't know if it's compatible between mac and PC.  (I tried it with 2 macs.  Worked pretty well.)

I also setup mouse gestures to go directly to the top and bottom of the file.  (great for huge log files)

Note: I have the MX Master, MX Master 2S, and MX Master 3.  I had trouble getting the 1 & 2S to work the way I wanted on the M2 chips (never had issues on the intel chips) but they were functional.  The cursor movement speed would max out well below my needs.  I did not have that issue with the 3.

*These have been my favorite mice for work for years.*

Comment: I swear by these mice (mouses?) I have the MX Master 3 on my Desk and the Anywhere 3 Mac edition in my laptop bag